# Get country main language by country code

Tags: node.js, country-codes, countries

Is there a way i can get a country main language by its country code?
I need something like `countries-list` npm package which gives me a list of spoken language codes by a country code.
An example of what i mean: 'en' => 'English'

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question. You say you want the main language, then you want list of spoken language codes by country code, then you give an example of language code to full language name. If you want a more precise answer, please be a bit more specic. :) But if you're happy with the resource Sofyane linked to you, just ignore me! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Rest Api  for country :
https://restcountries.com/

Answer (score 1):

The CLDR contains this information, you can see a table here: https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/44/supplemental/territory_language_information.html

To use the data in Node.js you can install the `cldr-core` package from NPM and import the `/supplemental/territoryInfo.json` file from there. You can see how it's structured here: https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr-json/blob/main/cldr-json/cldr-core/supplemental/territoryInfo.json
Writing a function to look up a country in that data and return its language codes should be pretty trivial.

If you want to convert the language code into a language name, the [Intl.DisplayNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DisplayNames) API can do it (it can convert country codes into names too).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-locale-map can return a default locale for each country